# How to use bind without losing `this` reference?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, dom-events

Is there a way to partially apply additional arguments to a function without losing the `this` binding given by an event handler. `bind` requires a `this` value, so putting null as the first argument loses the reference to the DOM element `<button>Click</button>` that would otherwise be present. It would be nice to supply addition arguments like `bind` allows without losing the reference to the element

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button')
function once(...args) {
  console.log(...args, this) // {prop: 'val'}, event, `Window`
  button.removeEventListener('click', bound)
}
const extraArgs = {
  prop: 'val'
}
const bound = once.bind(null, extraArgs)
button.addEventListener('click', bound)
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

In this example, the effect could be achieved by just passing in `button` as the first argument to bind, but I am interested in not "losing" the bound `this`, not replacing it with a reference to the element.

#### How can extra arguments be supplied to a function without losing the `this` DOM element binding?

Comment: Pass `this` as the first argument? It's really unclear what you're asking.

Comment: There **has** to be a dupetarget for this but I'm not immediately finding it. Basically, you have to write a "curry" function: `function curry(fn, ...args1) { return function(...args2) { return fn.call(this, ...args1, ...args2); }; }`

Comment: Also `.bind()` doesn't do anything with `=>` functions, does it?

Comment: @Pointy You are correct. I missed that when I was writing out the example.

Comment: Notice you can still access the element using `event.currentTarget`

Answer (score 4):

There **has** to be a dupetarget for this. Basically, you have to write a "curry" function:

```
function curry(fn, ...args1) {
    return function(...args2) {
        return fn.call(this, ...args1, ...args2);
    };
}
```

That function creates and returns a function that, when called, calls the original passing along the `this` it was called with, providing the curried arguments followed by the arguments provided to the call to the curried function. The curried function returns the result of calling the original so that that result is seen by the caller.

Live Example:

```js
function partial(fn, ...args1) {
    return function(...args2) {
        return fn.call(this, ...args1, ...args2);
    };
}

class Example {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.withArgs = partial(this.method, 1);
    }
    method(a, b, c) {
        console.log(`this.name = ${this.name}, ${a}, ${b}, ${c}`);
    }
}

const e = new Example("example");
e.withArgs(2, 3); // this.name = example, 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Why do you need to `return` the `fn.call`?

Comment: @1252748 - `fn.call` calls `fn` setting `this` to `call`'s first argument, with the arguments supplied in its second argument onward. I return  the result it provides so that if the original function has a return value, it gets returned by the curried function.

Comment: Thanks. I reposted that comment to make it clear I was specifically asking about the `return` but looks like I submitted it just after you posted the answer. That answers it. Cheers.

Comment: _"There **has** to be a dupetarget for this"_. > What do you mean by "dupetarget"?

Comment: @1252748 - SO slang. A dupetarget is a question that's already been asked and answered that can be used as the target of a "close as duplicate" vote. I figured there had to be one, but I couldn't find it, and I notice no one has since, so... :-)